# My tilemap is semi-transparent

Tags: unity, tilemap

I am new to Unity, and I am following the following tutorial:
https://code2d.wordpress.com/2020/07/21/tilemaps/

However, my tilemap is semi-transparent. Any way to remove the transparency somehow? See attached screenshot.

[image: semi-transparent tilemap]

Comment: Are you sure there's no transparency in the images you used for the tiles, or the tint colours you assigned to them? (I have to ask because you did not show this configuration in your question)

Comment: Or having a big transparent button from an UI component sitting on top of it

Comment: The colors of each tile in the tilemap have an alpha of 255 in the UI, so I did verify this. Zibelas, the project is relatively empty. I can't imagine there'd be some UI component there already?

Comment: The point is that we shouldn't have to use our imaginations. Your question should show all the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem, starting from a new, empty project.